# Is it necessary for a round function $F$ in a Feistel cipher to be pseudorandom?

Tags: provable-security, pseudo-random-function, feistel-network, indistinguishability

I stumbled across [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/are-there-any-specific-requirements-for-the-function-f-in-a-feistel-cipher) where the questioner asked for specific requirements for the round function $F$ in a Feistel network so that the construction is secure. The answer explained that a pseudorandom function in a four round Feistel cipher is sufficient for it to achieve security.

Is that also necessarily the case? In other words, can a Feistel cipher be constructed with a round function that is not a PRF?

Comment: The Feistel circuit converts a PRF into a PRP. If not a PRF, what are you planning to have as F?

Comment: @user93353 This is exactly the question, is there an F that is not a PRF but the Feistel network still gives a PRP?

Comment: Could you explain what is _not a PRF_ for you? See Tiny Encryption Algorithm (TEA) that uses simple round operations and it is secure with sufficient rounds.

Comment: @kelalaka I used PRF as defined by the rigorous mathematical definition. But if I understand TEA correctly, I think this is already a counter example. Thank you!